# How to add n number of emails in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a user registration form which contains of firstname,lastname,email etc.

Here a user can add n number of emails.For this,I have created a button and onClick it should open the input field.

<--Here is the code -->

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
})
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newStudent = {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      email,
}
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newStudent);
      await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/student`, body, config);
}

  const handleClick = () => {

return <Input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />

  };
return (
  <Form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <Input
              id="standard-multiline-flexible"
              label="First Name"
              multiline
              name="firstname"
              value={firstname}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Input
              id="standard-multiline-flexible"
              label="Last Name"
              name="lastname"
              value={lastname}
              onChange={handleChange}
              multiline
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Input
              id="standard-multiline-static"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={email}
              multiline
            />
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>
              Add 
            </button>
          <PrimaryButton>Submit</PrimaryButton>
        </Form>
)
```

Can anyone tell me how should I define the handleClick() so that whenever I click the add button,it renders a new Input field?

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could achieve this if you want the user to see their input emails remove them etc is to do the following:

Create an emails state array.

Add an email text field with an add button next to it.

When the user enters an email and presses add, add that email to the array.

You can then map the array to show the added emails as a list with the option to delete the emails if the user decides to.

Comment: Ok.That  is really helpful.Thanks.

Comment: @anuragsarma you're welcome. consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it proved helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of handle click

Instead of doing this

`return <Input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />`

Do this ->

`setFormData({firstname: "",lastname: "",email: ""});`

**Edits**

1. You can display the emails via a list after making the API call
2. You can have a delete button to delete that email from the list.

"There are n ways to implement. Please be more specific"

Comment: I don't see how that would show up for the user or if the user decides to delete some?